# Can't locate origin of null pointer exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

How can I avoid `NullPointerExceptions`? I have tried using `try-catch` blocks but that didn't work.

My program is supposed to get data from Google Calendar. I am getting many elements, but here it is just one element as an example...

```
for (Iterator<?> i = eventsToday.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
    Component component = (Component) i.next();
    String Attachement=null;
    if(component.getProperty(Property.ATTACH).toString().trim()!=null){
        Attachement=component.getProperty(Property.ATTACH).toString();
    }
}
```

Could someone please help me with this.

Comment: What's `component`? What's `Property`?

Comment: post the stacktrace and more code.  Need more info.

Comment: If you are getting a null reference exception on component, that means it has been disposed of.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Test if `component.getProperty() == null` the null pointer exception is due to the `toString()` being called on a null object. The following example will work. (replace `Object o` with the real type returned by `getProperty()`)

```
String Attachment;
Object o = component.getProperty(Property.ATTACH);
if(o != null) {
   Attachment = component.getProperty(Property.ATTACH).toString();
}
```

Comment: i think this was the reason. but why  string has problem what is the reason can you explain me please

Comment: @VICKY-TSC You are tring to call a method `toString()` on a null object,

Comment: Ooh ok ok i was calling it yes i got it. thank you so much @secretformula

Answer (score 0):

Problem is likely that

```
component.getProperty(Property.ATTACH)
```

is returning null

Just add some code that checks

```
if (component.getProperty(Property.ATTACH)) {
    Attachement = component.getProperty(Property.ATTACH).toString();
}
```

You probably want to cache `component.getProperty(Property.ATTACH)`

Comment: But isn't `null.toString()`, just `\0`?

Comment: @ColeJohnson If you do something like `System.out.println(null)`, I think it outputs the string `null`. Trying to call any method on a null pointer will cause a NPE